# Sort lists by using LambdaExpression in "complex types"

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda, linq-expressions

everyone. I've tried in the past couple of hours to find an answer with Google and desperate tests using Immediate Window, but I think I'm not making the correct questions.

I have an OrderByExtender in my application, which I use to do sorts just using the property name and a boolean to tell if it's ASC or DESC sort.

```
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, string key, bool isAscending)
    {
        LambdaExpression sortLambda = BuildLambda<T>(key);

        if (isAscending)
            return collection.OrderBy((Func<T, object>)sortLambda.Compile());
        else
            return collection.OrderByDescending((Func<T, object>)sortLambda.Compile());
    }

    private static LambdaExpression BuildLambda<T>(string key)
    {
        ParameterExpression TParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        LambdaExpression sortLambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(TParameterExpression, key), typeof(object)), TParameterExpression);
        return sortLambda;
    }
```

It works like a charm when I use common-type properties (string, int, etc). But now I came up with the following scenario: I have an object called **BusinessOrder**, and inside it there is a property with the type **Quarter**. This Quarter object has three properties: Year(int), Quarter(int) and Abbreviation(string). I must do the OrderBy using the Abbreviation property. In other words, I must do:

```
BusinessOrderList.OrderBy(b => b.Quarter.Abbreviation);
```

But I want to put this kind of sort possibility inside my Extender, by passing as **key** parameter something like "Quarter.Abbreviation" and the Extender method understands that it's a matter of getting the property inside a "complex object".

I believe there's something I could do inside the "Expression.Lambda" method that creates the **sortLambda** variable, but I couldn't figure out how to replicate this behavior using Expressions. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access complex property in one step. You must build expressions chain recursively:

```
    private Func<TInput, object> BuildLambda<TInput>(string complexPropertyPath)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInput), "p");

        var propertyPathParts = complexPropertyPath.Split('.');
        MemberExpression complexPropertyAccessExpression = null;
        foreach (var propertyPathPart in propertyPathParts)
        {
            complexPropertyAccessExpression = complexPropertyAccessExpression == null
                ? Expression.Property(parameter, propertyPathPart)
                : Expression.Property(complexPropertyAccessExpression, propertyPathPart);
        }

        var lambda = (Func<TInput, object>)Expression.Lambda(complexPropertyAccessExpression, parameter).Compile();

        return lambda;
    }
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! Couldn't be better! It's the kind of thing that I wanted to do, just doesn't have the needed knowledge! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would recommend replacing the `string key` parameter with a `Expression<Func<T, object>> key` parameter. That way, your function call can be `BusinessOrderList.OrderBy(b => b.Quarter.Abbreviation);` just as you described. Since all the OrderBy/OrderByDescending methods accept this expression as an alternative to a string anyway, I don't see what benefit you derive from keeping `key` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Func` for sorting your collection

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
                           Func<IEnumerable<T>,IOrderedEnumerable<T>> OrderBy)
{
    if(OrderBy != null)
        return OrderBy(collection);
    return collection; 
}
```

You have to call it like this

```
{
    Func<IEnumerable<Book>,IOrderedEnumerable<Book>> sort = 
    list => list.OrderBy(B=>B.Author.Name).ThenByDescending(B=>B.Title) ; 

    List.OrderBy(sort);

}
```